# how to move particles

Tags: python, simulation

I am working on a pandemic simulation with python using `qt-designer`. The first thing I need to do is making moving particle. I used `FuncAnim` to make them move but it didnt work.

This is my work:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
import random

population = 100

class particle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.y = 5 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.vx = 5 * np.random.random_sample() - 0.5 / 5
        self.vy = 5 * np.random.random_sample() - 0.5 / 5     

    def move(self):
        if self.x < 0 or self.x >= 5:
            self.vx *= -1
        if self.y < 0 or self.y >= 5:
            self.vy *= -1
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

    def animate(self):
        for pi in pop:
            pi.move()
            d, = self._static_ax.plot([particle.x for particle in pop],
                                      [particle.y for particle in pop], 'go')
            d.set_data([particle.x for particle in pop],
                       [particle.y for particle in pop])

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=200, interval=450, repeat=True)


pop = [particle() for i in range(population)]
```

Comment: first: you have wrong indentations and `anim = ...` is not inside method. You can't get normal code and put in `Class` without changes.

Comment: what meas "didn't work"? Do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not commen) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't understand your class - why do you put `animate` and `anim = ...` in class? This way every particle will have own `animate` and own `anim = ... ` but there should be only one `animate` and one `anim = ...` - and rather they shouldn't be part of `particle`

Answer (score 2):

`Animate` and `anim = ...` shouldn't be part of class `Particle`.

You mix two methods of animation

- `plot()` which would need to clear/remove particles before new plot
- `set_data()` which doesn't need to clear/remove particles before new plot

and I keep the second method because it is simpler.

But second method doesn't update `x,y` limits and I need `ax` to set limits manually.

In `animate` you should `plot()` or `set_data()` after all moves, not inside `for`-loop.

And finally I need `plt.show()` to see it.

[image]

---

Working code:

I changed `vx`, `vy` for much smaller - so particles don't jump from one size to another but move smoother. And I changed `interval` for smaller to make it faster.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
import random

# --- classes --- # PEP8: `UpperCaseName`

class Particle:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.y = 5 * np.random.random_sample()
        #self.vx = 5 * np.random.random_sample() - 0.5 / 5
        #self.vy = 5 * np.random.random_sample() - 0.5 / 5     
        self.vx = np.random.random_sample() / 5
        self.vy = np.random.random_sample() / 5     

    def move(self):
        if self.x < 0 or self.x >= 5:
            self.vx *= -1
        if self.y < 0 or self.y >= 5:
            self.vy *= -1
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

# --- functions ---

def animate(frame_number):
    print('frame_number:', frame_number)

    # move all particles
    for pi in pop:
        pi.move()
        
    # after `for`-loop    
    
    # update data without ploting (`FunAnimation` will plot it for us)
    d.set_data([particle.x for particle in pop], [particle.y for particle in pop])
    
    # it would have to return `data` only when we use `blit=True` in `FuncAnimation`
    #return d,
    
# --- main ---

population = 100

pop = [Particle() for i in range(population)]

fig = plt.gcf()
ax  = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 5), ylim=(0, 5))
# draw first plot
d,  = plt.plot([particle.x for particle in pop], [particle.y for particle in pop], 'go')
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=45, repeat=True)#, blit=True)

plt.show()

anim.save('particles.gif', fps=25)
#anim.save('particles.gif', writer='ffmpeg', fps=25)
#anim.save('particles.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=25)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which use `plot()` instead of `set_data()`.

It automatically changes limits so it display region little bigger then `0..5` because sometimes `particles` leave this region.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
import random

# --- classes ---

class Particle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5 * np.random.random_sample()
        self.y = 5 * np.random.random_sample()
        #self.vx = 5 * np.random.random_sample() - 0.5 / 5
        #self.vy = 5 * np.random.random_sample() - 0.5 / 5     
        self.vx = np.random.random_sample() / 5
        self.vy = np.random.random_sample() / 5     

    def move(self):
        if self.x < 0 or self.x >= 5:
            self.vx *= -1
        if self.y < 0 or self.y >= 5:
            self.vy *= -1
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

# --- functions ---

def animate(frame_number):
    global d  # need it to remove old plot

    print('frame_number:', frame_number)
    
    # move all particles
    for pi in pop:
        pi.move()

    # after for-loop    

    # remove old plot
    #d.set_data([], [])
    d.remove()
    
    # create new plot
    d, = plt.plot([particle.x for particle in pop], [particle.y for particle in pop], 'go')

# --- main ---

population = 100

pop = [Particle() for i in range(population)]

fig = plt.gcf()
# draw first plot
d,  = plt.plot([particle.x for particle in pop], [particle.y for particle in pop], 'go')
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=45, repeat=True)

plt.show()

anim.save('particles.gif', fps=25)
#anim.save('particles.gif', writer='ffmpeg', fps=25)
#anim.save('particles.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=25)
```

Comment: That's cool! I'm wondering of how to implement the collision between particles. Do you have any idea?